# How to call 2 observables based on an input from form field (Angular) and only subscribe once

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs-observables

I have the following scenario.

1. there is a form control like `get cars(): FormControl { return this.parentForm?.get('cars') as FormControl; }`
2. I want to subscribe to a service `getAttributes()` using the cars result as a parameter and also subscribe to any further changes listening for `valueChanges` on `cars` form control
3. But how can I combine all of this into one subscription. I don't want to have 2

```
ngOnInit() {
  //getting initial value from the form 
  this.carsId = this.cars.value
  if (this.carsId) {
    this.getAttributes(this.carsId).subscribe()
  }

  //subscribing to any future changes in the form
  this.cars.value.valueChanges().pipe(
    map(result => {
      this.getAttributes(result)
    })
  ).subscribe()
}

...

get cars(): FormControl {  return this.parentForm?.get('cars') as FormControl;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an observable that emits both the initial value of the form and the changes by using `startWith`:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.cars.value.valueChanges().pipe(
    startWith(this.cars.value),
    switchMap(result => this.getAttributes(result))
  ).subscribe()
}
```

If you need to filter out empty values, just add a `filter`:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.cars.value.valueChanges().pipe(
    startWith(this.cars.value),
    filter(result => !!result),
    switchMap(result => this.getAttributes(result))
  ).subscribe()
}
```

Comment: What if the `this.getAttributes(result)` in switchMap is an Observable too, and needs a subscribe. It's not working for me if I try this

Comment: `switchMap` will internally subscribe to the observable from `this.getAttributes()` and emit its emissions.  What do you mean "it's not working"?

Comment: Not sure what I'm doing wrong then, I have the following: `return this.getAttributes(result).pipe(map( .... ) )` inside of the `switchMap`

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "not working"?  Does it give an error? Does it emit the wrong data?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working. Your solution works, but my editor for some reason asked me to put in `async` inside the switchMap like `switchMap(async(result))`. That was the problem. I removed it and it works now :). Appreciate your help!